# Angular 7 testing fails, not able to understand the reason. Any one help me?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to check the contact list, event without the existence. But my test getting fail. ( see `component.contacts.length` )

here is my testing code : `contacts.component.spec`

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts.component';
import { ContactClass } from './../shared/models/contact'

describe('ContactsComponent Tests', () => {
  let component: ContactsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ContactsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be no contacts if there is no data', () => {
    expect(component.contacts.length).toBe(0); ---> fails!!
  });

});
```

my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

error:

```
ContactsComponent Tests should be no contacts if there is no data
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: I don't see `contacts` attribute in your component, and can you post the error log ?

Comment: @madjaoue - error added, please check in question part

Comment: Well the problem is your class `ContactsComponent` does not have a `contacts` attribute. So inside your tests, `component.contacts` is equal to `undefined`. So `component.contacts.length` is actually equivalent to `undefined.length`, and the error says that `undefined`don't have length property.

Comment: Did you forget to add something like `contacts = []` in your ContactComponent ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have contacts array as variable within your component